# What the “that” word here is for？

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning, word-choice, word-meaning

I am reading Neil Gaiman‘s article [Credo](https://www.chino.k12.ca.us/cms/lib/CA01902308/Centricity/Domain/4327/Credo.pdf). There is a sentence like this:

> I believe that you can set your own ideas against ideas you dislike.
> **That** you should be free to argue, explain, clarify, debate, offend,
> insult, rage, mock, sing, dramatize, and deny.

I think the "that" word starting the second sentence is not grammatical right and can be omitted. I just would like to know what the “that” word where is for？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two sentences are an enumeration, sharing the same beginning. But the beginning is omitted the second time around:

> I believe that you can set your own ideas against ideas you dislike. I believe that you should be free to argue, explain, clarify, debate, offend, insult, rage, mock, sing, dramatize, and deny.

Comment: Got it. Thanks very much

Comment: It would be helpful to add that _that_ is a subordinator introducing a declarative content clause. The sentence would benefit from a colon after "dislike".